# How to configure internal url's content on Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony1, web

I am new to Symfony and I am trying to understand how a Symfony project works. Right now I am trying to change the content of an internal url. For example, in the layout.php file, I can put a sentence like:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('viajesDeusto/new') ?>">Suecia</a>
```

This works fine, when I press 'Suecia' "Button"  it changes the content, and it adds viajesDeusto/new to the url. My question is, where can I change the content that the "viajesDeusto/new' url displays?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the url in your `url_for()` function it breaks out to MODULE/ACTION

So go into your app (%SF_ROOT_DIR%/apps/%APP_NAME%)
inside that folder you have a `modules` folder 
inside that you have the module name
inside that you have an `actions` folder and a `templates` folder
the `actions` folder is where your code to retrieve/process data resides
the `templates` folder is where the presentation code resides

For instance, if your app is called `frontend` the location of the code is:

%SF_ROOT_DIR%/apps/frontend/modules/viajesDeusto/actions
%SF_ROOT_DIR%/apps/frontend/modules/viajesDeusto/templates

This is the standard setup for syfony 1.x apps